# Send email to various addresses from cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have in "Sheet1" numerous email addresses, in columns K, M, O, Q, S, U, W, Y, AA.
I want to create an email that will be sent to all the addresses taken from the last row in Sheet1. Same for data in email body taken from last row.

```
Dim MonOutlook As Object
Dim MonMessage As Object
Dim EmailTo As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    EmailTo = .Range("K" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("M" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("O" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("Q" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("S" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("U" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("W" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("Y" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("AA" & ligne)
End With

Set MonOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MonMessage = MonOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    MonMessage.To = ""
    MonMessage.Cc = ""
    MonMessage.Bcc = EmailTo
    MonMessage.Subject = "Rate request" & " " & "for" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & ligne)
    MonMessage.body = "Hello,"
                Chr (13) & Chr(13) & "Please send me rate for" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & ligne) & " " & "rooms on basis" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "in hotel:" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "for the period" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("suivi").Range("C" & ligne) & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Thank you!" & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Application.UserName & " " & "-" & " " & "x Tours"

    MonMessage.Display

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB" & ligne)
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmailContactsLastRow()

Dim MonOutlook As Object
Dim MonMessage As Object
Dim EmailSht As Worksheet
Dim EmailTo As String
Dim ligne As Long

' set the worksheet object
Set EmailSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With EmailSht
    ligne = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column K

    EmailTo = .Range("K" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("M" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("O" & ligne) & ";" & _
            .Range("Q" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("S" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("U" & ligne) & ";" & _
            .Range("W" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("Y" & ligne) & ";" & .Range("AA" & ligne)
End With

Set MonOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MonMessage = MonOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With MonMessage
    .To = ""
    .Cc = ""
    .Bcc = EmailTo
    .Subject = "Rate request" & " " & "for" & " " & EmailSht.Range("B" & ligne)
    .body = "Hello,"
                Chr (13) & Chr(13) & "Please send me rate for" & " " & EmailSht.Range("G" & ligne) & " " & "rooms on basis" & " " & EmailSht.Range("H" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "in hotel:" & " " & EmailSht.Range("J" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "for the period" & " " & EmailSht.Range("C" & ligne) & " " & EmailSht.Range("D" & ligne) & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Thank you!" & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & Application.UserName & " " & "-" & " " & "x Tours"

    .Display ' <-- this displays the email. not sending it
    .send ' <-- this sends the email out
End With

With EmailSht.Range("AB" & ligne)
    .Value = Date
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But when i write the number of row I want send to email, it doesn't work :( I want to choose number of row, and then an email is created with data included in this row. If there are more than one hotel, then this email will be generated for each hotel (included in the chosen row), only the name of the hotel will change in the email body message, and of course the email address will be only this hotel only. This macro will work again until the last email in the chosen row (I remember that email addresses are in column K, M, O, Q, S, U, W, Y and AA)/ Thank you!

Comment: There is a userform (UserForm3) with a text box where I write row# (txbSend) : 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.txbSend <> "" Then Call SendEmail(CLng(Me.txbSend))
Unload Me
End Sub